# How to Create and Add Stickers and Smiley's In You Own Application

Tags: android

I have made an Android IM Application, and I'm trying to add some stickers and smileys to it, but after lots of searching, seems there is no training about it and where to Start.

I imagine it's a pain or PNG that is added to the TextView right? Can someone please put me in the right way? Even if I just know What "type" are they (png, paint, canvas, etc...), I could make my own way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText with SpannableStringBuilder and ImageSpan doesn't works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534427/edittext-with-spannablestringbuilder-and-imagespan-doesnt-works-fine)

Comment: so its SpannableStringBuilder, Thanks alot, that will do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make java add an image view with the image in your drawable folder. Don't know how this would work but try somthing.

Comment: not image view, its spannableStringbuilder, Knowing this i could find tutorials