# Suggestion Edittext Android with small image

Tags: android, image, android-edittext, country

Can `EditText` display suggestion with small images when type ?

**for example :** when i type "Un", then `EditText` will show United states of america with its flag, and united kingdom with its flag.

is this possible to do? or using spinner ?

Thansk for your help all.

Comment: You can use AutoCompleteTextView with a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible  you will have to customize AutoCompleteTextView for this.
Please refer below link this is pretty much same what you want to do :-

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the suggestions while writing text inside your EditText then use AutoCompleteTextView with a custom adapter as suggested by @Milanix.

If you want to show Images then use SpannableString and Display Images using ImageSpan.[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494054/imagespan-on-edittext-smileys-with-swiftkey-keyboard-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Use **AutocompleteTextView** to do so. It is very simple make one List (List) of possible strings you want to suggest . Make one **ArrayAdapter** give the list of strings to adapter and set this array adapter to **AutocompleteTextView**. That's it.