# Using spannable in edittext in android

Tags: android, hashmap, android-edittext, textwatcher, spannable

I put this code from answer [Displaying emoticons in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android?rq=1) for showing emoticons in Edittext but I have a problem when I'm typing a lot of text, it becomes slower and slower and almost impossible to type. 
This is the code: How can I make it faster?

```
 textS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                addSmiledText(Main.this, s);
               // Log.e("",s.toString());

            }
        });}


     private static final HashMap<String, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     static {
         emoticons.put(":)", R.drawable.face_smile);
         emoticons.put(":-)", R.drawable.face_smile);
         emoticons.put(":(", R.drawable.face_sad);
         emoticons.put(":-(", R.drawable.face_sad);
         emoticons.put(":-D", R.drawable.face_smile_big);
         emoticons.put(":D", R.drawable.face_smile_big);
         emoticons.put(":lol:", R.drawable.face_laughing);
            emoticons.put("8)", R.drawable.face_cool);
            emoticons.put(";)", R.drawable.face_wink);
           emoticons.put(";-)", R.drawable.face_wink);
            emoticons.put(";(", R.drawable.face_crying);
           ...

     }
     public static Spannable addSmiledText(Context ch, Editable s) {

            int index;
            for (index = 0; index < s.length(); index++) {
                for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
                    int length = entry.getKey().length();
                    if (index + length > s.length())
                        continue;
                    if (s.subSequence(index, index + length).toString().equals(entry.getKey())) {
                        s.setSpan(new ImageSpan(ch, entry.getValue()), index, index + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        index += length - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Comment: When you profiled your code with Traceview, what did you find?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html What you will find is that scanning a character at a time through the entire string is not a very efficient way of seeing if the last-typed character somehow creates an emoticon.

Comment: I know that is not efficient but how to make it to scan only two last characters? For examle, I insert "ab" it scans=ab, then I add "c"= "abc" it scans only bc.

Comment: Maybe you should look at using TransformationMethod, which seemed to be designed for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to make it to scan only two last characters?

You have:

```
for (index = 0; index < s.length(); index++)
```

If you do not want to scan the entire string each time, **choose a better starting value for `index`**.

For example, since your minimum-length emoticon has two characters and your maximum-length emoticon has five characters, skip the loop entirely for `Editable` objects of length 0 or 1, and then have `index` start at `s.length()-5`.

Note, though, that `afterTextChanged()` is not only called for changes at the end. The user might have repositioned the cursor to be somewhere in the middle. Hence, you really should be scanning in `onTextChanged()` and looking at the window of text around the point of the change.

Comment: Thank you for guidelines, I'll try to set it like this. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: Ok, I'm trying for two days to make it work and nothing... If I can set it to range from s.length()-5, it won't show emoticons. It only works in this way like I posted above but it is very slow. So I don't really know what to do anymore. Maybe I should try it in some completely other way, what do you think? Is this a bad way to do that?

Comment: @Natasa.M: I have never attempted to implement an emoticon converter algorithm. That being said, others *have* implemented them, probably hundreds of times, so I would focus on finding an efficient existing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In order to scan last 2 characters instead of

```
for (index = 0; index < s.length(); index++)
```

use

```
int start = s.length() - 1;
int end = start - 2;
for (index = start; index > end; index--)
```

This way you start looping from the last element backwards until you looped 2 positions.