# How to pass Emoticons and Text from Activity to next using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, textview, android-edittext

I want to pass text and emoticons from `EditText` of one `Activity` to second `Activity` to show it in `TextView` and also I want to use this data in second `Activity`. e.g if user wants to edit data this data in second `Activity` so they can. I am passing the data simply through `Intent` in this way:

Sending:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Template.this, Data.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);
```

to get data

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
textView.setText(message);
```

But in `TextView` it is not showing emoticons and also I don't know how to use it further from `Intent`.

[image: screenshot of EditText with emoticon and text]

Any Help in this Regard. Thanks

Comment: show how you're doing it w/ code

Comment: Sending:
Intent intent = new Intent(Template.this, Data.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        String message = editText.getText().toString(); 
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);
to get data
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
        textView.setText(message);

Answer (score 1):

send emotion string  like :D :) by intent and get it in another activity and build it by Spannable.

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4302199/603233