# Storing Spannable to a string

Tags: android, imageview, emoticons

i'm writing a chat application, and to parse emotion icons i use code from here [Displaying emoticons in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android?rq=1)

my chat text is stored like "SENDER|TIME|NON_PARSED_CHAT_TEXT" in an ArrayList

the problem is that i have all chat messages (time and sender and chat text) in a single string, and i split it and display it in a row in a ListView, each time i get this chat text and re-parse it for the emotion icons, is there any possible way to store Spannable object (chat text after parsing resulted from the function in the question provided) to string in an ArrayList with the time and sender?

thanks

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any possible way to store Spannable object (chat text after parsing resulted from the function in the question provided) to string in an ArrayList with the time and sender?

You are welcome to use [`toHtml()` on the `Html` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml%28android.text.Spanned%29), though that can only handle some HTML output, not arbitrary things.

You could also have an `ArrayList` that holds the `Spannable` rather than a `String` conversion of that `Spannable`.

Comment: wont the toHtml() do the same thing? search text for <img> tag and replace it everytime? same as Spannable?

Comment: @killercode: `toHtml()` takes a `Spannable` and generates HTML. You are thinking of `fromHtml()`, which takes HTML and generates a `Spannable`.

Comment: so, you mean i should parse the emotion icons like usual, use Html.toHtml() and then store result as string? i'm going to try that now

Comment: @killercode: To be honest, I am completely lost as to what you are trying to do overall. You asked how to "store Spannable object... to string", which is what I am trying to answer.

Comment: yes, store Spannable to string while keeping it's parsed state, so next time i want to load the chat text from the array list, it displays it directly, without the need or re-parsing String to Spannable again, i tried Html.toHtml, it displays "<p><img src="null"></p>"

Comment: @killercode: "store Spannable to string while keeping it's parsed state" -- by definition, that is not possible. That's like saying "I want to store a float to string while keeping it as a float" or "I want to store a Restaurant to string while keeping its parsed state".

Comment: so the only option is to use ArrayList<Spannable> ?

Comment: @killercode: "so the only option is to use ArrayList<Spannable> ?" -- I can't speak for the `ArrayList` part, but the most straightforward way to keep a `Spannable` would be to keep a `Spannable`.