# android unable to show emoticons image?

Tags: android, xmpp

i am making an chatting application in which i am sending emoticons smileys to user.My emoticons opreation is working partial.,but problem is that when i am sending any smiley image its going in object from and also showing in object form.,like this

[image]

and i want to show smiley which i have pointed in blue circle.i am so confused and finding this solution from 3 days but not successed in that..,what i do please hel pme..,here is my code

here is adapter class

```
  Msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Msg);
            //Msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(nameAndText[1] ));

            //               TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView2 );
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(nameAndText[1]);
            //Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.emoticon );

            //ssb.setSpan(smiley, 16, 17, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );    
            Msg.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );

            System.out.println("<ssssssssssssssss>>>>>>>>."+Msg.toString());
```

and following this link[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android)

Thanks in advance